# C++ architecture for compile-time array dimensionality and named indexing

Tags: c++, architecture

I can work with code in C++, but it's not where I spend most of my time. I usually work in another language, where, over the course of my career, I have put together a well defined architecture for building predictor/corrector (e.g Kalman filter) type algorithms that are easily maintained and modified. For the sake of a ground up deployment of a recently designed filter, **I am hoping to replicate this architecture within a C++ framework.** Hopefully, we can get the same level of extensibility built into the deployed product, so I don't need to keep jumping back-and-forth to another language whenever I want to modify the model being used by the filter.

The idea here is that we're going to have an array that contains a bunch of different information about the state of a given system. Let's say, for example, we have a an object with a position and orientation in 3D... We'll use a quaternion for the orientation, but the specifics of that aren't super important.

Here's some pseudo-code to demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
function build_model()

    model.add_state('quaternion',[0;0;0;1],[1;1;1]);
    model.add_state('position',[0;0;0],[10;10;10]);

    model.add_input('velocity',[0;0;0]);
    model.add_input('angular_rate',[0;0;0]);

    model.add_noise('velocity_noise',[1;1;1]);    
    model.add_noise('angular_rate_noise',0.01*[1;1;1]);

end
```

where the above have the form:

```
add_state(state_name, initial_state_estimate, init_error_std_deviation_estimate)

add_input(input_name, initial_input_value)

add_noise(noise_name, noise_std_deviation)
```

After calling build_model() happens, I end up with a bunch of information about the estimator.

- The state space is of dimension 7
- The state error space is of dimension 6
- The input vector is of dimension 6
- The "process noise" vector is of dimension 6

Further (indexed from 0), I have some arrays, such that:

- state[0:3] holds the quaternion
- state[4:6] holds the position
- state_err[0:2] holds quaternion error
- state_err[3:5] holds position error
- input[0:2] holds velocity
- input[3:5] holds angular_rate
- process_noise[0:2] holds velocity noise
- process_noise[3:5] holds angular rate noise

... but, I don't want a bunch of hard-coded indices... in fact, once the model is built, the rest of the code should be designed to be completely agnostic to the positions/dimensions/etc of the variables/model/state/error-space etc.

Since the estimator and the model don't really care about each other, I try to keep them encapsulated... i.e. the estimator just has state/error/noise of known dimensions and processes it with functions of a generic format, and then the model specific stuff is presented in the appropriate format. This, unfortunately, makes using an indexed array (rather than a struct or something) preferable.

**Essentially what I'm looking for, is a pre-compiler way to associate names (like a structure) and indices (like an array) with the same data... ideally building it up piece by piece using simple language as shown above, to a final dimension, determined by the pre-compiler based on the model definition, to be used for defining the size of various arrays within the estimator runtime algorithm.**

I'm not looking for someone to do this for me, but I'd love a push in the right direction. Good architecture early pays dividends in the long run, so I'm willing to invest some time to get it right.

So, a couple of things I've thought about:

There are definitely ways to do this at run-time with dynamic memory and things like std:vector, structures, enums, and so forth. But, since the deployed version of this is going to be running in real-time, performance is an issue... besides, all of this stuff shouldn't need to happen at run-time anyway. If we had sufficiently sophisticated precompiler, it could just calculate all of this out, define some constants/macros/whatever to manipulate the model by name while using indices behind the scenes... unfortunately, fancy precompiler stuff is a pretty niche area that I have little experience with.

It seems like template meta-programming and/or macros might be a way to go, but I'm hesitant to dive head-first into that without guidance, and I recognize that this is shady at best in terms of modern software design.

I could always write code to write the C++ code for me... i.e. spit out a bunch of #defines or enums for the indices by name, as well as the dimensionality of the model/estimator components, and just copy paste this into the C++ code... but that feels wrong for different reasons. On the other hand, that's one way to get a "sufficiently sophisticated pre-compiler".

Giving up on the compile-time dimensioning of my arrays would also solve the problem, but since the all of this is constant once computed, run-time seems like the wrong place for it...

So, is there an elegant solution out there? I'd hate to just brute force this, but I don't see a clear alternative. Also, much of the above may be WAY OFF for any number of reasons... apologies if so, and I appreciate any input you might have :-)

Comment: To fully answer this question requires someone with sufficient expertise in both C++ and Matlab. I venture to guess there won't be a lot of people like that, here on stackoverflow.com. You apparently are trying to figure out how to do something in C++. In which case I would suggest that you reframe, and then [edit] your question in terms of C++ terms only, without any mention of Matlab. Describe what you are trying to do in C++, and explain exactly what your specific question is, regarding the C++ programming language.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @SamVarshavchik, I'll try to reframe...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting most of the way there using template meta-programming... [see below]

I'd like to find a way to add the state to `state_enum` and define its corresponding `set_state` struct at the same time ie:

`add_state(quaternion,{0,0,0,1},{1,1,1})`

just for cleanliness and to prevent one happening without the other... if anyone has ideas on how to do this (preferably without using `__COUNTER__` or boost), let me know. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

struct state_enum{
    enum{quaternion,position,last};
};

template <int state_num> struct set_state{
    static constexpr double x0[] = {};
    static constexpr double sx0[] = {};
};

template <> struct set_state<state_enum::quaternion>{
    static constexpr double x0[] = {0,0,0,1};
    static constexpr double sx0[] = {1,1,1};
};

template <> struct set_state<state_enum::position>{
    static constexpr double x0[] = {0,0,0};
    static constexpr double sx0[] = {2,2,2};
};

template <int state_num> struct state{

    enum{
        m_x  = sizeof(set_state<state_num>::x0)/sizeof(set_state<state_num>::x0[0]),
        m_dx = sizeof(set_state<state_num>::sx0)/sizeof(set_state<state_num>::sx0[0])
    };
    enum{
        m_x_cummulative = state<state_num-1>::m_x_cummulative+m_x,
        m_dx_cummulative=state<state_num-1>::m_dx_cummulative+m_dx,
        i_x0=state<state_num-1>::m_x_cummulative,
        i_dx0=state<state_num-1>::m_dx_cummulative,
        i_x1=state<state_num-1>::m_x_cummulative+m_x-1,
        i_dx1=state<state_num-1>::m_dx_cummulative+m_dx-1
    };
};

template <> struct state<-1>{
    enum{m_x = 0, m_dx=0};
    enum{m_x_cummulative = 0, m_dx_cummulative=0, i_x0 = 0, i_dx0=0, i_x1 = 0, i_dx1=0};
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::cout << "Summary of model indexing and dimensions...\n\n";
    std::printf("%-32s %02i\n","quaternion  first state index",state<state_enum::quaternion>::i_x0);
    std::printf("%-32s %02i\n","quaternion  final state index",state<state_enum::quaternion>::i_x1);
    std::printf("%-32s %02i\n","position    first state index",state<state_enum::position>::i_x0);
    std::printf("%-32s %02i\n","position    final state index",state<state_enum::position>::i_x1);
    std::printf("%-32s %02i\n","full state vector dimensionality",state<state_enum::last>::m_x_cummulative);
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::printf("%-32s %02i\n","quaternion  first error index",state<state_enum::quaternion>::i_dx0);
    std::printf("%-32s %02i\n","quaternion  final error index",state<state_enum::quaternion>::i_dx1);
    std::printf("%-32s %02i\n","position    first error index",state<state_enum::position>::i_dx0);
    std::printf("%-32s %02i\n","position    final error index",state<state_enum::position>::i_dx1);
    std::printf("%-32s %02i\n","full error vector dimensionality",state<state_enum::last>::m_dx_cummulative);
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```